# codeigniter: how to get json date from api, send it to the view page

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter. I am looking for your help here..

if i  open this url http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&random=1403540243  then i get some json date on my browser,

How can i call the same url and read those all json date send it same to my view page in Codeigniter  ?

I tried like this,but its sending the url not reading the data under this url

```
public function getAllJsonData() {//first version
        $data['all_json_data'] = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&random=1403540243";
        $this->load->view('myViewPage', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    public function getAllJsonData() {//first version
            $data['data'] = file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&random=1403540243');
//        $data['data'] = json_decode($data, true);
            $this->load->view('myViewPage', $data);
        }
```

paste below code on view file

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data; 
?>
```

Comment: then how will display these json on my view page??

Comment: on view print_r($data);

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'data'

Comment: now coming, but the problem is its showing data in the form of array...  I want data as it shows when you click this url:http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&random=1403540243      http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140623-zxnd-71kb.jpg

Comment: @obama: I check my answer again